# Select statement to call stored procedure generating error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to call the stored procedure in select statement of SQL server. When I call the stored procedure it is generating error.

What can be wrong in the below select statement??

```
Select i.item as col1, exec StoreProc_name(i.item) as col2
from tbl_item as i where i.item>100
```

This is not working. What is the right way to call stored procedure in   SQL server.

Comment: Can you post the code for the stored proc? I think what you want is a function, but depending on what the proc does, you may not need it at all.

Comment: Why cant you write StoreProc_name(i.item) as a function.
Thats much more easy to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table as (
    col2 as int
);

insert @table(col2) 
exec StoredProc_name i.item;
```

This of course doesn't work as part of a query, but only in a (not recommended) cursor - so check into defining a [Inline Table-Valued Function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx) to replace your stored procedure.

Note that your stored procedure should begin with this statement in order to be usable by OLEDB and ADO:

```
set nocount on;
```